# Who is the spirited king Vasumitra, the reincarnation of Danayu's son Vikshara?

Tags: mahabharata, avatars, spirituality, kings

The eldest of the four sons of Danayu, who was known by the name of Vikshara, became known on earth the spirited monarch, Vasumitra

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm

> The **eldest of the four sons of Danayu**, who was **known by the name of Vikshara, became known on earth the spirited monarch, Vasumitra.**